# UI button OnClicked attribute compiles but crashes UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm quite new still to C++ so have been trying to find some basic class examples which might help with this problem. The ones I found helped initially but now I'm getting stuck with an engine crash related somehow to my code.

This is particularly about unreal engine slate UI buttons in a custom editor plugin, but I think it may just be a C++ issue.

The .OnClicked attribute of my button is set to a delegate, the project compiles fine in VS2015 but as soon as I select the editor plugin tab in UE4, the engine crashes.

**FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit.h**

```
class FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit : public FModeToolkit
{
public:
    FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit();
    FReply GetPercentage();
};
```

**FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit.cpp**

```
FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit::FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit()
{
    //rest of the UI code
    SNew(SButton)
    .Text(FText::FromString("Log Percentage"))
    .OnClicked(this, &FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit::GetPercentage)
    //rest of the UI code
}
...
FReply FVASFVPluginEdModeToolkit::GetPercentage()
{
    return FReply::Handled();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, you can see that I'm not trying to do anything fancy yet, just get the delegate function to return that it worked!

Commenting out the .OnClicked lets the project compile and the editor plugin loads fine, so I'm assuming the error is something to do with my function or how I'm setting up the .OnClicked.

When the crash happens, there is "No minidump found", and the crash log doesn't seem to contain any useful information:

**Crash Log**

> [2016.03.11-15.45.17:425][422]LogWindows:Error: Windows GetLastError: The operation completed successfully. (0)
>   [2016.03.11-15.45.17:657][422]LogCrashTracker: 
>   [2016.03.11-15.45.17:658][422]LogCrashTracker: 
>   [2016.03.11-15.45.17:658][422]LogWindows:Error: === Critical error: ===
>    Assertion failed: SharedThis.Get() == this [File:D:\BuildFarm\buildmachine_++depot+UE4-Releases+4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\SharedPointer.h] [Line: 1093]

Comment: Could you share what you've learned from running this in a debugger?

Comment: Just ran it with the VS2015 debugger and got back that "Assertion failed: SharedThis.Get() == this [File:D:\BuildFarm\buildmachine_++depot+UE4-Releases+4.10\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\SharedPointer.h] [Line: 1093]".  
Helpfully the UE4 source code has some comments around there which say  If the following assert goes off, it means one of the following:
- You tried to request a shared pointer before the object was ever assigned to one. (e.g. constructor)
- You tried to request a shared pointer while the object is being destroyed (destructor chain)  
But I'm not sure how to fix

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use OnClicked_Raw()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).